# How can I get all matches of a regex in a string?

Tags: regex, perl, curl

How can I use `curl` to get the contents of any html tag?
In the following script to get e.g. `h1` contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $page = `curl www.yahoo.com`;  
print "Page: \n";  
sleep(5);  
#print "$page \n";  
if ($page =~ m/<h1\s*>(.*)<\/h1\s*>/ig){  
        print "$1 \n";  
}
```

I get just one match. How can I get all matches?

Comment: FYI, you could use Perl's LWP modules instead of curl.

Comment: @squiguy:I did not know about these

Comment: [For your browsing](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the matches like this:

```
my @matches = $page =~ /<h1\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h1>/ig;

print "@matches\n";
```

*(But note that on yahoo.com, there is a single h1 tag)*

Answer (score 2):

[Parsing HTML with regexes is a sin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1521179). Luckily, there are many parsers lying around. I am especially fond of the Mojo suite:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mojo;

my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new(max_redirects => 5);  # redirects defaults to zero
for my $h3 ($ua->get('www.stackoverflow.com')->res->dom('h3')->each) { # use CSS selectors
  say $h3->all_text;
}
```

- [Mojo on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo)
- [Mojolicious homepage](http://mojolicio.us/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a **while** loop instead of **if**:

```
while ($page =~ m/<h1\s*>(.*)<\/h1\s*>/ig) {  
    print "$1 \n";  
}
```